# Append a period/dot at the end of the string in a tinymce text editor data

Tags: php

Currently my data is saved in mysql database as below from tinymce textarea. I need to append a period or dot at the end of the string while displaying the data in html. Below is the example.

Data stored in database

```
<strong>Hello World </strong>
```

I need to add the period at end of string when a string is not ending with a period or exclamation mark or a question mark.

When i append a period at the end of string like mentioned above it display "**Hello World** ." in HTML. A space comes between a word "World" and a period. I need to remove that space with removing the HTML tags.

My PHP code to append the a period at the end of the string. It perfectly works when there is not HTML tag or if the string is not ending with HTML tags

```
$val = "<strong>Hello World </strong>";
$string_to_replace = array("<br />","&nbsp;","&nbsp; ");
$val = str_replace("\\r\\n",' ', $val );
$val = trim(stripslashes($val));
$val = trim(str_replace($string_to_replace,'', $val ));
$val_without_tag = trim(strip_tags($val));
$val_without_tag = str_replace($string_to_replace,'', $val_without_tag );

$last_val = substr($val_without_tag,-1);
$regularexp = array('.','!','?');
if(!empty($last_val)){

   if(in_Array($last_val, $regularexp)){
        return $val;
    }
    else {
    return $val.". ";
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to keep the html tags on the text? for example the `<strong>` ?

Comment: Yes i need to keep the HTML tag like <strong></strong> or any other html tags. Just need to view same like wysiwyg but append a period at end.

Comment: so the appended '.' will be *inside* the `<strong>Hello World </strong>` or outside? please provide the desired *HTML source code (not the browser rendered)* result for this `<strong>Ending with a space </strong>`

Comment: Desired HTML source code is <strong>Hello World.</strong> if we can find out the last html tag of string. Their might be cases like  <strong>Hello World </strong><em>test</em> where i need to append the period at end of the HTML string.

Comment: I am using tinymce text editor to store my data in database. I just need to append the period at the end of the string if period is not present at the end of the string.

Comment: by saying *at the end of the string* what do you mean by *string*? What you get from your db? Or what you see RENDERED in your browser? if string is this `<strong>ending with a space </strong>` this does not ends with space, it ends with `>`. if you consider string what you see RENDERED in your browser then this `<strong>ending with a space </space>` will produce **ending with a space** this ends with a space. please clarify and provide the desired **html code result** for this string you are getting from db `<strong>Ending with a space </strong>`

Comment: HTML which i get from db is `<strong>Hello World </strong>` i need to display a period at end of the Word "Hello World." in my browser with Hello World in Strong.

Comment: HTML which i get from db is `<strong>Hello World </strong>` i need to display a period at end of the Word "**Hello World**." in my browser with **Hello World** in Strong.

Comment: so you need this result A) `<strong>Hello World</strong>.` or this B) `<strong>Hello World.</strong>` or this C) `<strong>Hello World </strong>.` or this D) `Hello World.`

Comment: Yes, option B if we can identify the last html tag of the source code and place a period with in the HTML tag.

Comment: @Sharky How abt giving an answer

Comment: any one who can assist me on the question...that would be great help

Answer (score 0):

My two cents, although it might not be beautiful.

I would do a backward search for "<". 
If its found, check if what's inside is a word (not another tag). 
If its a word, put the period in the position where "<" was found -1 (if it was found at pos 123, the period goes in 122).

I'll try to upload some code for this as soon as I get near a computer.