# TinyMce - Append a period at end of last tag

Tags: php, regex

Below is the just an example of source code from tinymce. Source code can contain any html tags. My requirement is Whatever source code is from tinymce, i need to append a period at the end of html source code which i am getting from tinymce. A period should be appended only if last character in source code is not a period or exclamation mark or question mark.

```
<strong>Hello World </strong>
```

i want to append a period/Dot at the end of the source code.

The output i require is

**Hello World**.

But i get output in HTML view

**Hello World** .

Note: I need the HTML tags from the source code to be exist while printing the text in browser so it won't affect.

How to remove the extra space before the period in PHP?

OR

Append a period at the end of my Source code.

My PHP source code to append period at end of the string

```
$val = "<strong>Hello World </strong>";
$string_to_replace = array("<br />","&nbsp;","&nbsp; ");
$val = str_replace("\\r\\n",' ', $val );
$val = trim(stripslashes($val));
$val = trim(str_replace($string_to_replace,'', $val ));
$val_without_tag = trim(strip_tags($val));
$val_without_tag = str_replace($string_to_replace,'', $val_without_tag );

$last_val = substr($val_without_tag,-1);
$regularexp = array('.','!','?');
if(!empty($last_val)){

   if(in_Array($last_val, $regularexp)){
        return $val;
    }
    else {
    return $val.". ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not concatenating the string with a dot? `$newstring = $string . '.'`?

Comment: Just now i have added my source code to in question above for appending a period at end of the string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Append a period/dot at the end of the string in a tinymce text editor data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908285/append-a-period-dot-at-the-end-of-the-string-in-a-tinymce-text-editor-data)

Comment: @Sharky you gone very deeply in the comprehension in the last question, so i thought u might know the answer

Comment: @Anup i just tried to clarify the question, then when it was clear what the user asked, i had no good-quality answer on that. at least my clarification will be useful to others to understand whats the desired result.

Comment: @sharky: i need your help... Please ask your friends who can help on the same question

Comment: @Praveen, You still need to add more details to your question. Show some more examples and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `DOM` parser.

```
<?php

$html='<strong>Hello World </strong>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
echo "<strong>".trim($dom->getElementsByTagName('strong')->item(0)->nodeValue).".</strong>";
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

**Hello World.**

Comment: tags in the HTML string can be any HTML tags like <b></b>, <i></i>, <em></em>, <span></span>... so can we use the above code?

Comment: When you write a question you should take the time to specify all those before posting. Can you edit your question and make all things clear first ?

Comment: You want the tags or just the text ?

Comment: i have update my question, i hope you will get some idea about my question. i want the both text with tags so it can view in HTML.